# Flex: Loader do not load if already loaded?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, loader

Is there some way to check if what you are loading is already in memory and don't need to be loaded a second time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is a non-issue. That sort of "loading" is handled by the browser's cache. If you load an image and then go to load it again and inspect the network traffic during that scenario, you will only really request and download the image once.

Comment: But I can see in debug mode that the loader is in fact loading the swf I'm loading and unloading it later on. Doesn't that mean that it is loading it time after time?

Comment: As far as managing the memory management of the experience, you may want to keep track of your loaded item in such a way that it either does not need to be reloaded over and over, or that you know it has been completely purged from memory so as not to leak. Otherwise, even though you are necessarily reloading the SWF, you're likely getting it from the browser cache.